# How to disable "tip" balloons in Edge browser?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

The Edge browser periodically displays "tip" balloons to draw attention to / explain the icons at the upper right. The tips also appear in the desktop notification "drawer". How do I turn them off? It's really annoying, especially when the same tips get displayed (and posted to the notification drawer) over and over.

Answer (score 4):

- Select Settings from the Start Menu
- Click the System Menu
- Click Notifications and Actions
- Turn off 'Show me Tips about Windows'

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about Cortana. You should be able to go to the Edge Settings, select Advanced Settings and Turn off Cortana.

Comment: I don't think this is Cortana. I get the same repetitive, annoying "tip" balloons (eg, "Cleaner Reading" and "Take Notes", over and over again). In Advanced Settings, the option "Have Cortana assist me in Microsoft Edge" is Off and Disabled with the message, "You must turn on system Cortana to enable this setting." Been that way for a while now, and I still get the same "helpful" tips once or thrice a week.